# Create a long list of characters (not numbers) with list comprehension

Tags: python

In Python how can I need to create a long list that I'm trying to avoid typing, the list looks lis this

```
brands = ['_1','_2','_3'... '_998']
```

I can create the list of numbers with a for loop, but I'm trying to use list comprehension for the characters which should be faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Speed is not a concern.  This is one-time initialization.  `brands = [f'_{k+1}' for k in range(998)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
my list=["_" + str(i) for i in range(1,999)]
```